# How can i send a X amount of numbers to a txt file in Java?

Tags: java, file-writing

I need to send X numbers to a txt file in Java and i have this:

```
for(int count = 0; count< amount; count++){                             
           text =text + array[count] + "\n";
           try(  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( "nums.txt" )  ){
                out.println(text);
            }//end try
           catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { 
Logger.getLogger(MainPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
            }//end catch
        }// end for
```

The thing is the txt file looks like this: 
[image: for 1500 numbers:]

How can i do to print one under the previous one?

i mean like:

```
1
2
3
```

... and so on.

Comment: You should initialize PrintWriter out of loop!

Comment: Do you know that in each iteration, you're adding a number to `array`, and then writing out the whole of `array` each time?

Comment: I know that but  didn't noticed it, thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

You're opening the file in notepad, so I guess you're using Windows.

```
text =text + array[count] + "\r\n";
```

`\r\n` is the Windows line separator.

Or you can use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to get the current platform's line separator.

Or you can use:

```
text += String.format("%s%n", array[count]);
```

Or you can use a `StringBuilder`, which avoids creating the `text` String quadratically:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int count = 0; count< amount; count++){
  sb.append(array[count]);
  sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
String text = sb.toString();
```

Or you can simply print in the loop, which avoids creating the `text` String at all:

```
try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("nums.txt")) {
  for(int count = 0; count< amount; count++){                             
    out.println(array[count]);
  }
}
```

Or you could use a better text editor that actually handles *nix-style line endings.

Comment: Thanks! i used \r :D

Comment: Pay close attention to SteveSmith's comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

By reversing your logic. You have:

```
loop:
  create and write to file
```

Do:

```
create new file
loop:
  write to file
```

instead.

In other words: your for loop should go **into** the try statement; instead of creating a new FileWriter() during each loop.

And of usual, Andy is correct: you want to use the "system dependent" newline character; so that the file does contain the correct newline when opening on your choice of OS.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the javadoc:

`public void println()`

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The
>   line separator string is defined by the system property
>   line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character
>   ('\n').

Which system are you working on ? Are you sure it is adding a proper new line ?

Also, As others mentioned, you should better open your stream and then loop to write into it using a StringBuilder.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop should be inside the try block not the other way around. Also with bufferedwriter you can use newLine() to add a new line to the file instead of using \n.

```
try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("nums.txt", true))){
    for (int count = 0; count < amount; count++) {                             
        text += array[count];
        bw.write(text);
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

    Logger.getLogger(MainPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
     }//end catch
```